# Write wide-character to stream

Tags: c, linux

I would like to write a wide-character to a file in C.

Here is what I do but it doesn't seem to work...the file remains empty.

```
wchar_t c = 0x2592;
FILE *file;
file = fopen("foo.txt","w");
fputwc(c, file);
```

Of course I put the `setlocale(LC_ALL, "fr_FR.utf8");` in the main function.

Answer (score 1):

Change setlocale parameters, after I've changed it it worked for me:

```
setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "fr_FR");
```

EDIT: The above I tested on Mac OS X. It seemed to work, the output file had 3 bytes.

Then when I tried the same on a Linux box (OpenSuse 11) it worked different: the result file had only one byte... So I changed it back to `setlocale(LC_ALL, "fr_FR.utf8");` and it worked seemingly OK, the output file had 3 bytes... So it seems like it's a bit system dependant, the functions are POSIX, but I think how they work depends on what languages you have installed or something like that... All the functions return error codes, you should check them. Read the manual of each function and see what error codes they can return.

Answer (score 0):

you need to flush the output for the character to be actually written:

```
fflush(file);
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: have you called it after writing the character ?

Comment: I just tried it, and I do have a character in the foo.txt file, which character 0x2592 is supposed to be ?

Comment: Also do you check for error, are you sure you have write permission on the file ?

Comment: The full programm is +600 lines.. I tried it and it seems to be working but when i use fputs("blabla",file) and fputwc(c, file) the wide caracter isn't written to the file but the "blabla" string is.. i don't understand